# Saving elapsed time in Julia 1.0.0

Tags: time, julia

```
temp=0
@elapsed for k in 1:1000
    global temp+=k
end
```

will return elapsed time. But how can you save this into a variable?

```
temp=0
time=@elapsed for k in 1:1000
    global temp+=k
end
```

I think this worked in previous versions of Julia? But for 1.0.0 I get

```
cannot assign variable libc.time from module Main
```

Also it does time the whole for loop correct? I'm really saddened by `tic` and `toc` being unusable in 1.0.0, I think the logic was simpler there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it quite clearly tells you that `time` is an existing variable (namely, a function) in `Main`:

```
julia> time
time (generic function with 2 methods)
```

So, just name your result differently:

```
julia> ime=@elapsed for k in 1:1000
           global temp+=k
       end
6.6707e-5

julia> ime
6.6707e-5
```

Comment: I see. It says 'cannot assign', instead of 'cannot assign to', so I thought the problem was on the right hand side.